# NullPointerException thrown while attempting to build AST from Jenkinsfile source

Tags: jenkins, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm attempting to parse a `Jenkinsfile` into an AST so I can perform validation on it (rather than using complex regular expressions).

In my `groovysh` session:

```
groovy:000> filePath = "/Users/ashleyconnor/Projects/Jenkins/Jenkinsfile"
===> /Users/ashleyconnor/Projects/Jenkins/Jenkinsfile

groovy:000> file = new File(filePath)
===> /Users/ashleyconnor/Projects/Jenkins/Jenkinsfile

groovy:000> ast = new AstBuilder().buildFromString(CompilePhase.CONVERSION, false, file.text)
ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException:
null
        at java_lang_Runnable$run.call (Unknown Source)
```

Writing the code to a sourcefile and running it via `groovy AST.groovy` produces a different error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CompilePhase for class: AST
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CompilePhase for class: AST
    at AST.run(AST.groovy:5)
```

The contents of the `Jenkinsfile` is available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabric8io/fabric8-jenkinsfile-library/master/maven/ReleaseStageApproveAndPromote/Jenkinsfile).

`Groovy Version: 2.5.7 JVM: 1.8.0_121 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`

Answer (score 1):

```
@Library('github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library@master')
```

I make this mistake half the time too, you need the trailing underscore.

```
@Library('github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library@master') _
```

AND maybe set your first line to just `#!groovy`.

AND I have a very odd feeling that those top level `def`s you have won't work in a Groovy Pipeline. Jenkins Groovy is... executed a bit differently in places than say Groovy on the command line. I would put those top level defs - and that `if` statement - *inside* the `node` closure. (I know you're trying some clever `isCD()` thing... but my advice is to get it working with everything in the `node` first, then add your if statements later.

Comment: I added the code you suggested and the issue remains.

Comment: @Ash give that another shot, I've editing my response with some more information and thoughts.

Comment: Hey Ryan I think you might have misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to run the code in the Jenkinsfile. I'm attempting to build an AST from it so I can validate it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the first two arguments to `buildFromString` solved the issue:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilder;

def filePath = "/Users/ashleyconnor/Projects/Jenkins/Jenkinsfile"
def file = new File(filePath)
def ast = new AstBuilder().buildFromString(file.text)
println(ast)
```

Output:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script200423567329429.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class Library ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 3, column 1.
   @Library('github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-pipeline-library@master')
   ^

Script200423567329429.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class io.fabric8.Utils
 @ line 5, column 13.
   def utils = new io.fabric8.Utils()
               ^

2 errors
```

Changing the `Jenkinsfile` to contain `println("Hello World")` produces an AST:

```
[org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement@d9f41[org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement@e8fd7[expression:org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression@e8fd7[object: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression@d9f41[variable: this] method: ConstantExpression[println] arguments: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression@eadde[ConstantExpression[Hello world]]]]]]
```

Although having all of the dependent libraries available locally isn't practical for what I'm trying to do.